# New Operator With Vectors

Tags: c++, vector, new-operator, operator-keyword

These questions are relatively straight forward. When using vectors, should I use the `new` operator when pushing back a new element? And which release method should I call? Here's what I mean:

```
// Release method: 1.
void ReleaseMethodOne( vector< int * > &ThisVector )
{
    // Clear out the vector.
    ThisVector.clear( );
    return;
}

// Release method: 2.
void ReleaseMethodTwo( vector< int * > &ThisVector )
{
    // Clear out the vector.
    for( unsigned uIndex( 0 ); uIndex < ThisVector.size( ); uIndex++ )
    {
        delete ThisVector.at( uIndex );
    }
    return;
}

int main( )
{
    vector< int * > Vector;

    // Add a new element.
    Vector.push_back( new int( 2 ) );

    // More code...

    // Free the elements before exiting. Which method should I call here?
    ReleaseMethodOne( Vector ); // This one?
    ReleaseMethodTwo( Vector ); // Or this one?

    return 0;
}
```

I've started learning vectors not long ago and the book I was learning from said that the vector's `clear( )` method called each of the elements destructor. Do this apply to the `new` operator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

STL containers store *copies* of the objects you give to them, pointers in your example. They never release any memory *you* explicitly allocated. You have to deallocate that memory yourself, so the second "release" method should be used.

Of course, you don't need to `new` every `int`. Just use `vector<int>` instead - you won't have to deal with manual memory management at all.

Answer (score 5):

The `clear` method will indeed call destructors. However, your vector is storing pointers, and the destructor for pointers is a trivial no-op. It does *not* call `delete`.

Therefore, simply calling `clear` will not free the memory for all the `int` objects you allocated with `new`. You need to `delete` them.

If you use a *smart pointer* instead of an ordinary pointer, then the pointed-at objects will get freed at the appropriate time without you having to do anything special.

Comment: OK. So if I replace the vector with this: "vector< auto_ptr< int > > Vector;" I won't have to use any of the methods?

Comment: NO! Don't use `auto_ptr` in containers. They don't meet the copy semantics requirements for containers. You'll need to use something like `shared_ptr` from Boost, tr1, or C++0x

Comment: A `shared_ptr` would be better; `auto_ptr` doesn't meet all the requirements for things that can be stored in STL containers.

Comment: @Hyper: As you can see, that's one of the failures of C++03. The best replacement, if it's available to you, is C++0x's `unique_ptr`. It cannot be copied, but it can be moved.

Comment: "Smart pointers" aside, does the vector allocate memory on the heap internally for new elements?

Comment: @Hyper: Not for new elements, per se. It is a contiguous buffer, so it allocates *a* buffer and uses it as a storage place for elements. But it doesn't allocate for *each* element. When it doesn't have enough room, it gets a new buffer of a new size (usually 1.5-2 times the current size), copies (moves in C++0x) the elements over, and uses that instead.

Comment: @Hyper, the vector allocates memory for all the elements. In your case, the elements are pointers. The vector does *not* allocate memory for the stuff the pointers *point at*. (That's why you need to use `new`, and why mere `clear` isn't enough to release the memory for the pointed-at `int` objects.) You should seriously consider whether `vector<int>` is more appropriate for your needs — it will let you avoid all this business of dynamic allocation.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `ReleaseMethodTwo()`, because if you've allocated the memory, then it's **your responsibility** to delete it.

`std::vector::clear()` only erases the elements from the vector. It doesn't call `delete` on the elements being erased!

Answer (score 2):

For what you are doing there you would need to use `ReleaseMethodTwo`.  What it means by saying that it calls the element's destructor is that contained classes (not contained pointers) will lose scope and have their destructors called.

No STL container will ever call `delete` for you, so far as I know.  If you allocate and pass in a pointer, you will need to deallocate.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by others, vector does call the destructor of each element. In your case, the elements are pointers and hence it will not free the memory.
For your application, the best choice is to use a reference counting smart pointer like boost:shared_ptr. Once there are no more references pointing to the elements (like the example you had written), the memory will be freed automagically.

PS: Do not use a "non-reference counting" smart pointer like std::auto_ptr with vector.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `vactor<int *>` than you'll have a vector of pointers and you have to allocate memory for each elements and free this memory yourself also. It doesn't make much sense to use vector of pointers unless the size of type you want to store in the vector is quite big.

Actually when you do `vector<T>::push_back(val)` is it going to store a copy of `val` using a copy constructor `T::T(T &orig)` and call destructor for all elements when you do `clear()`

Comment: Storing large objects is not a very good reason to use pointers.  Especially since all good compilers now support rvalue references.

Comment: I didn't say that it is a good reason, but it could be useful in some cases.